# Alert function for 30 minutes - Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a simple if condition which checks the current minute for triggering an alert. But it is not getting triggered.

```
if minute(timenow)==30
    alert("ALERT!!",alert.freq_once_per_bar )
```

The alert is getting triggering for other conditions. Is the alert function will not work for a time-based condition?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems to work fine when tested. Keep in mind that the script executes on bar close, so if there is no bar that closes on 30 minute (for example if there are no trades to create a bar or if the exchange is closed) the script will not run at all

Comment: Thanks for your reply @mr_statler. I am not using freq_once_per_bar_close, instead, I am using freq_once_per_bar so I hope the alert will trigger before the candle close. Does that work for you? Strange! 
I am getting a notification when I create an alert. Please see the screenshot below.
https://ibb.co/Ht0hgmw

Comment: Running only those lines of code works without issues for me so maybe the issue is not here

Comment: There is no other code https://ibb.co/bWv3RWt

Comment: What timeframe do you use ?

Comment: I am using 15 minutes